# How to use the fileupload control in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, file-upload

I'm using a fileupload control to upload images. The upload is working but I would like to know how to display the uploaded image. For example,

1. user uploads file, (already done);
2. the image is displayed in the page.

Comment: it is not possible to show the image before uploading. you need to use flash or silverlight for that. otherwise you are able to show them after upload on server.

Comment: i want to show them after the upload not before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an image control in your aspx page, and in the upload button event , add the URL of the image to the Image Control.

You can set the Image control visibility with false in the beginning and in the PostPack set it back to true to view your image.